# Bang & small flames when I tried to jump start, now nothing

Tags: electrical, battery, starter, jump-start

I tried to jump start my car (a 2006 Ford Focus, 1,600 cc) and there was a bang and small flames.

Now, nothing happens when I try to start the car. Can anyone tell me what could have happened?

Comment: Sounds like you put the jumper cables on backwards and now you have a bunch of burnt fuses/wires. You might also have burnt out your alternator. Start pulling fuses and checking them. Replace as needed. Then see from there.

Comment: Can you add more to your post?   As much information as you can.  The more information we have the higher the likelihood that someone can help you.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: I made a short at an edit, could you check it to see if I got it right?

Comment: Where were the flames?  Under the hood or out your exhaust or......?

Answer (score 3):

A "bang and flames" around a battery has two likely sources:

1. Igniting the hydrogen gas that is produced when it charges. This can happen when there are sparks as you connect the second jumper cable. Because of this it is a good idea to attach the ground (black) cable second and attach it to the engine block or some other ground(ed) point away from the battery. That keeps the sparks away from the hydrogen and that is good.
2. Shorting the positive terminal while hooking up the battery, that will be quite dramatic with lots of sparks and noise. I'm not sure I'd expect a bang, but the noise would certainly be sudden. The most dramatic way to do this is what @Paulster suggests – hooking up the cables backwards. The result of that should be some *very* dramatic sparks as you hook up the last cable along with a sizzling sound. If you persist in making the connection, the sparks and sound will go away, but the batteries and jumper cables will start cooking.

The second scenario is likely to do a lot of damage to the batteries of both cars, if one of the cars is running it might put quite a load on the alternator as well. That is likely to blow the alternator output fuse – I didn't have any luck finding an image of one for your car, but if you follow the heavy lead from the alternator towards the battery you should find it. If you don't have an alternator output fuse, you may find that the alternator output lead itself has started to overheat and melt.

Despite all of the drama, I suspect that the damage will be relatively limited, probably just to the battery or batteries and maybe the alternator and it

Comment: It is phenomenally difficult to get greater than 4% concentration of Hydrogen outside of the battery. You would literally have to establish specific conditions in a controlled setting to achieve this. Not gonna' happen in your car.